# Cannot connect to Digital Ocean Server with Filezilla

Tags: ubuntu, lamp

I have a LAMP server I created and am trying to upload files to it. When I try and log in on filezilla I use my IP user name and port but I get this error:

```
Status:         Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
Error:          Cannot establish FTP connection to an SFTP server. Please select proper protocol.
Error:          Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

I can log in with that user name and password from their online console easily, but I am now trying to upload files.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, "Cannot establish FTP connection to an SFTP server."  So in the Filezilla Site Manager, you need to choose protocol SFTP instead of FTP for that connection.